# Int won't add to a variable even if code has no errors

Tags: java

I'm working on my first java project and I have a problem with my code, when buying "tokens" from shop.

The code has no errors but it won't give me tokens.
When I do /buy Token it will also not work properly, here is some output from the command :

/buy Token
You've successfully bought a Token!
< - Doesn't work properly, and put the if and else output.

You don't have enough coins to buy a Token!

/tokens < - trying to do another command, it won't work.

/tokens < - trying to do another command, it won't work.

Thanks for helping if you do so.

Class 1 :

```
package Main;
import mining.Betterfarm;
import coins.Tokens;
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class to write text for buying in the shop
import coins.Bank;

public class Shop {
    public Shop() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean BetterFarm;
        boolean running;
        BetterFarm = false;
        boolean ShorterDelay;
        ShorterDelay = false;
        boolean Token;
        Token = false;
        running = true;


        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t            •••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••   ");
        System.out.println("\t\t           •••                                                                  •••   ");
        System.out.println("\t\t          •••                       Welcome to our shop!                         •••   ");
        System.out.println("\t\t           •••                                                                  •••   ");
        System.out.println("\t\t            •••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••   ");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t               ⛏ 1. Buy BetterFarm - 3000 Coins (farm faster and more efficient!) ⛏");
        System.out.println("\t\t               \uD83D\uDCA8 2. Buy ShorterDelay - 2000 Coins (this way you don't have to wait so long!) \uD83D\uDCA8");
        System.out.println("\t\t               \uD83C\uDFB0 3. Buy Token for Casino - 1000 Coins \uD83C\uDFB0");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t               \uD83D\uDCD9 Commands:");
        System.out.println("\t\t               \uD83D\uDCD9 BetterFarm: /buy BetterFarm \uD83D\uDCD9");
        System.out.println("\t\t               \uD83D\uDCD9 ShorterDelay: /buy ShorterDelay \uD83D\uDCD9");
        System.out.println("\t\t               \uD83D\uDCD9 Token: /buy Token \uD83D\uDCD9");
        System.out.println("\n");

        while (running) {
            String in = input.nextLine();

            if (in.equals("/buy BetterFarm")) {
                BetterFarm = true;
            }

            while (BetterFarm) {
                if (Bank.amount >= 3000) {
                    System.out.println("You've successfully bought BetterFarm!");
                    Betterfarm.lvlup();
                    Bank.amount = Bank.amount - 3000;

                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You don't have enough coins to buy BetterFarm!");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (in.equals("/buy ShorterDelay")) {
                ShorterDelay = true;
            }

            while (ShorterDelay) {
                if (Tokens.amount >= 2000) {
                    System.out.println("You've successfully bought ShorterDelay!");
                    Tokens.amount = Tokens.amount - 2000;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You don't have enough coins to buy ShorterDelay!");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (in.equals("/buy Token") && Bank.amount >= 1000) {
                System.out.println("You've successfully bought a Token!");
                Bank.amount = Bank.amount - 1000;
                Tokens.amount = Tokens.amount + 1;
            }

            if (in.equals("/buy Token") && Bank.amount < 1000) {
                System.out.println("You don't have enough coins to buy a Token!");

            }


            if (in.equals("/tokens")) {
                Tokens.getAmount();
            }


            if (in.equals("/stop")) {
                break; }

            if (in.equals("/shop")) {
                Shop shop = new Shop();
            }

            }
        }
    }
```

Class 2 :

```
package coins;

public class Tokens {
    public static int amount = 1;

    public static int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void add(int amount) {
        this.amount = this.amount + 1;
    }

    public void del(int amount) {
        this.amount -= 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you're abusing constructor of Shop (constructors are supposed to create instance of a class, not run the entire process) as well as static and instance members/fields in class `Tokens` and possibly `Bank`

Comment: @AlexRudenko is right. Consturctor are supposed to create instance. You have to do all the process under void main(){}.

Comment: So @AlexRudenko, should I transfer all of this code into my main.java ? Or just under public class Shop {

Comment: @Sdev, my point is that you should separate creation of `Shop`, `Bank`, `Tokens` from their processing/handling in driver class(es).

Comment: Your code for buying tokens doesn't have an `if` and an `else` case - it has two `if` cases. Assuming that the starting amount in the bank account was 1500 when you type in `/buy Tokens` then both cases will execute because the code in the first `if` reduces the amount in the bank account by 1000, leading to the condition `Bank.amount < 1000` also being true.

Answer (score 0):

put your process stage into the main class. other 3 class is your Objects. You can't handle the process into an Object constructor.